# How can a device without the capability to snoop memory access on bus maintain its cache validity?

Tags: memory, x86

I am trying to understand the MTRR (Memory Type Region Register) in Intel processor. From the Intel Manual, I see this about the WT cache control:

> Write-through (WT) — Writes and reads to and from system memory are
>   cached. Reads come from cache lines on cache hits; read misses cause
>   cache fills. Speculative reads are allowed. All writes are written to
>   a cache line (when possible) and through to system memory. When
>   writing through to memory, invalid cache lines are never filled, and
>   valid cache lines are either filled or invalidated. Write combining is
>   allowed. This type of cache-control is appropriate for frame buffers
>   or ***when there are devices on the system bus that access system memory,
>   but do not perform snooping of memory accesses.*** It enforces coherency
>   between caches in the processors and system memory.

As I understand, the ability to snoop the system bus for memory access signals is the ***key pre-requisite*** for a device to maintain its *own* cache validity (and possibly help others to achieve that). But for a device without such capability, how does it know when to invalidate its cache?

Comment: Just FYI, I've never seen any discussion of actually using WT memory for anything except performance experiments (vs. uncacheable or WB for microbenchmarks or certain workloads).  I hadn't realized that it didn't fill on writes, but that makes sense.  Anyway, feel free to skip WT, and just pay attention to WB vs. UC vs. USWC.

Comment: It doesn't. That's the purpose of WT: write data all the way up to memory so that memory can act as the official source of data. Simple put, PCI devices can do DMA.

Comment: I think the key point here is that the *device* can't have a cache, or if it does, it doesn't stay coherent.  But it can read from main memory and always see whatever the CPUs agree is there.

Comment: @MargaretBloom So, with DMA, PCI devices just *directly* read data from memory *whenever* they need? Does this mean PCI devices have no read-cache at all?

Comment: Yes, exactly what Peter said. PCI devices can read (and write) to memory, depending on the nature of the device they can or cannot have a cache. If they do it is the OS responsibility to be aware of it. It's not coherent. Of course, the PCI bus topology and its devices vary a lot. What said applies to a standard x86 PC.